# WebdriverIO/Cucumber/Allure reporting issues

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs, allure

I've followed all of the steps for getting a system setup using webdriverio and cucumber for some end to end testing and the next thing I wanted to take care of was reporting. Found allure reporting too which is great and works pretty much out if the box. I have two things I need fixed however,

1. I can see that allure is reporting each of the steps ran however, it appears that the steps are order alphabetically (which is not very useful in debugging and trying to reproduce). Is there a way to add sorting by timestamp to steps within a suite?

and

2. For the custom reporter, I can do `this.on('suite:start', (suite) => {` etc. but I would like to know what is the correct term to plug into each step. I know there's a `beforeStep:` method that we can use in the `wdio.conf` but i would like the reporter to determine where to do the logging. What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are native filters in the report that you can filter by order:

[image]